# Send Contact Form not Working

Tags: php

I've followed a simple tutorial for a send contact form, however it appears to be not working. Please can someone assist please.

Form below:

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="send.php" method="post" name="form1">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="16%">Name</td>
                                <td width="2%">:</td>
                                <td width="82%"><input id="Name" type="text" name="Name" size="50" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input id="customer_mail" type="text" name="customer_mail" size="50" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Subject</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input id="Subject" type="text" name="Subject" size="50" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Detail</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><textarea id="detail" cols="50" name="detail" rows="4"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    $to ='kirsty.harris1985@gmail.com';

    $header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

    $mail_from="$customer_mail";
    $Subject="$Subject";
    $detail="$detail";

    $send_contact=mail($to,$header,$Subject,$detail);

    if($send_contact){
        echo "We've recived your contact information";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
?>
```

This is the error:

Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://nqmedia.co.uk/send_contact.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

And also the website is www.nqmedia.co.uk for people to see it.

Comment: What isn't working about it? No email? Error message? Getting your "ERROR" text displayed to you?

Comment: you're missing `$_POST` in your php code. Also, make sure to check your spam folder in gmail.

Comment: im getting an error of configured incorrectly. The website is nqmedia.co.uk on the contact page

Comment: @AustinAllover sorry where do i place this? it didnt have that in the tutorial :S

Comment: Are you postitive post.php is in the same folder?

Comment: @Pachonk positive it is in the correct folder

Comment: @KirstyHarris. The problem is with the `mail()` function, you have the order of the parameters wrong. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and my answer below for other problems with your PHP code

Comment: hi nine7ysix.. i may just use a plugin... as this is out of my league

Comment: @KirstyHarris , I can't believe I missed this. The error shows "send_contact.php", but on your form, the action parameter sends the form to "send.php". This might be the problem. Change the action parameter to have the value "send_contact.php".

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP to the following:

```
<?php
    $to ='kirsty.harris1985@gmail.com';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $customer_mail = $_POST['customer_mail'];
    $Subject = $_POST['Subject'];
    $detail = $_POST['detail'];

    $header="From: $name <$customer_mail>";

    $send_contact=mail($to,$Subject,$detail,$header);

    if($send_contact){
        echo "We've recived your contact information";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }

?>
```

1. No variable was defined properly, you needed to use `$_POST` to retrive the values from the form.
2. `$mail_from` (now `$customer_mail`) was used before it was defined.
3. The parameters used in the in the `mail()` function were used in the wrong order. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
4. Check the `action` attribute on your form. It says "send.php", but the error shows "send_contact.php"

Comment: Hi @nine7ySix, so i swap these around then? Sorry clearly the tutorial wasnt a great one :S

Comment: Oh, you're missing the `$_POST`s. Look at ElefantPhace's answer

Comment: @KirstyHarris, can add the line `echo print_r($_POST)` to your PHP code and update your question to show what is displayed? EDIT: `$name` is not defined... =.= Try adding `$name = $_POST['name']` somewhere;

Comment: Hi, ive changed the code to the guys above with the post actions and it still not working :S

Comment: @KirstyHarris, I've updated my answer, can you try to see if it works now? I'm positive it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Given that your inputs are named accordingly
try this:

```
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];
$header = "from: $name <$mail_from>";
$Subject = $_POST['Subject'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually grab all the post values.

Make this your code for send.php:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];
$subject = $_POST['Name'];
$body = $_POST['detail'];

$to ='kirsty.harris1985@gmail.com';

$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

$send_contact=mail($to,$Subject,$body,$header);

if($send_contact){
echo "We've received your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Also, you misspelling "received" on your echo, so I fixed the spelling mistake.

Comment: Hi there, I updated my code with this and it is still not working :S

Comment: i do not understand what you mean by that :s

Comment: If you go to your root folder of your ftp, you should see a file named ".htaccess". post the contents of that.

Comment: 0_o... what does that do though? Sorry im not confident with this,

Comment: I'm assuming that your .htaccess is having a rewrite rule conflicting with your post.

Comment: hmmm.... ok, i will have a look at something else, as this is confusing me. Doesnt help following a tutorial that CLEARLY doesnt work

Comment: I actually think it's an error on your part, quite possibly. Do you know what an ftp is?

Comment: Do you have an htaccess in your root folder?